# PHP short-circuit evaluation

Tags: php, operators, short-circuiting

I have this code:

```
if (!in_array('array_item', $body) || !is_int($body['array_item']))
    throw new Exception();
```

Now due to short-circuiting I would expect `is_int` not to execute if `array_item` does not exist in `$body`. However I still get complaints from PHP about "undefined index array_item", which I assume is from `$body['array_item']`.

Can someone explain to me why `$body['array_item']` is executed if `is_int` isn't?

Comment: works fine on my php 7.0.8 install. `||` issues no warnings.

Comment: @chris85: wrong. if it was `&&`, both would have to be tested. that's why it's `||` to allow short-circuit. if any part of an `or` is true, then the whole thing is true, meaning the later terms can be skipped.

Comment: Ah misread that. Yup, that makes sense. No notices here https://3v4l.org/hnHM8

Comment: @Mark B I'm on php 5.5.8, so I guess I'm a bit out of date, but still.

Comment: maybe you can do something like this for the other side in_array('array_item', $body) ? !is_int($body['array_item']) : false

Comment: @Eli: Good idea, unfortunately I still get the same error. As a matter of fact I still get the error even if it's wrapped several levels in if-statements. I wonder if this is a bug or if I have done something stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) looks for a *value* in an array. If you want to see, if a key exists, use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead

```
if (!array_key_exists('array_item', $body) || !is_int($body['array_item']))
    throw new Exception();
```